# Nested Constraint layouts and huge layout inflation times

Tags: java, android, xml, android-constraintlayout

I have a lot of layouts like below. Also the same with NestedScrollView instead of the CardView.

But in all cases this leads to nested constraint layouts. Particuallary in one screen I use the following a lot as a custom view type. But this leads to HUGE inflation times. I meassured 500 ms and more. This is of course unaccaptable.

What can I do to improve the layout performance. The custom view is an EditText that looks like
[image: Custom EditText]

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!--Some layout code -->
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>


<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/cardView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**EDIT: As per request. Here comes the complete xml, java, and how I use it in another xml**

CustomEditText.xml:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clipChildren="false"
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:paddingStart="8dp"
android:paddingTop="9dp"
android:paddingEnd="8dp">


<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
    app:cardElevation="3dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_goneMarginBottom="10dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_startIcon"
            android:layout_width="19dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="19dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:tint="?attr/colorPrimary"
            tools:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_phone"
            tools:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_prefix_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="19dp"
            android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            tools:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="ABC" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
            android:id="@+id/barrier_start"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:barrierDirection="end"
            app:constraint_referenced_ids="tv_prefix_text,iv_startIcon" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/et_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="19dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/barrier_end"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/barrier_start"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
         />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_hint"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:layout_marginEnd="57dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/barrier_start"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:hint="Hint text" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
            android:id="@+id/barrier_end"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:barrierDirection="left"
            app:constraint_referenced_ids="iv_endIcon,tv_optional" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_optional"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="19dp"
            android:alpha="0.44"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/edit_text_optional"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:visibility="visible" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_endIcon"
            android:layout_width="39dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="18dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="18dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/barrier_end"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_alert"
            tools:tint="?colorError"
            tools:visibility="visible" />

        <androidx.core.widget.ContentLoadingProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pb_loading"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
          />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>


<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_count"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
    android:alpha="0.44"
    android:textSize="9sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:fontFamily="@font/nunito2"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/cardView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView"
    tools:text="0/30"
    tools:visibility="visible" />

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_helper"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:alpha="0.44"
    android:textSize="9sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tv_count"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/cardView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView"
    app:layout_goneMarginEnd="19dp"
    tools:text="Helper text"
    tools:visibility="visible" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and the CustomEditText.java (Sorry, this is a lot of code. But as I do not know what is important I could not reduce):

```
public class CustomEditText extends LinearLayoutCompat {
private static final String TAG = "CustomEditText";
private static final String ANDROID_NS = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";
private static final String APP_NS = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto";
private static final String COUNTER_SEPARATOR = "/";
private static final int TRANSLATION_Y_DP = 21;
private final int translationY;
private static final float HELPER_ALPHA = 0.44f;
private final String counterErrorText;
private final List<TextWatcher> textWatcherList = new ArrayList<>();

private final Drawable alertIcon;
private final Drawable clearIcon;


private final CustomEditTextBinding b;

private String errorText;

private String helperText;

private String hintText;

private Drawable startIcon;
private int iconTint;

private int counterMaxLength;

private boolean isCounterEnabled;

private boolean isOptional;

private boolean isProgressBarVisible = false;

private boolean isClearEnabled;

private boolean hasFocus;

private boolean isError = false;

private boolean isCounterError = false;

private String prefixText;

private final boolean initialized;

private final boolean hasBorder;


public CustomEditText(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    b = CustomEditTextBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), this, true);
    b.tvHint.setPivotX(0);
    b.pbLoading.hide();
    translationY = GuiUtils.dpToPx(context, TRANSLATION_Y_DP);
    alertIcon = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.icon_alert);
    clearIcon = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.icon_clear);


    counterErrorText = context.getString(R.string.counter_max_length_error);

    TypedArray attributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomEditText);

    //Start icon
    startIcon = attributes.getDrawable(R.styleable.CustomEditText_startIcon);
    iconTint = attributes.getColor(R.styleable.CustomEditText_iconTint, ColorUtils.getAttrColor(context, R.attr.colorPrimary));
    refreshStartIcon();

    //Hint text
    hintText = attributes.getString(R.styleable.CustomEditText_hint);
    refreshHintText();

    //Helper text
    helperText = attributes.getString(R.styleable.CustomEditText_helperText);
    refreshHelperText();

    //Error text
    errorText = attributes.getString(R.styleable.CustomEditText_errorText);

    //Prefix text
    prefixText = attributes.getString(R.styleable.CustomEditText_prefixText);
    refreshPrefixText();

    isClearEnabled = attributes.getBoolean(R.styleable.CustomEditText_clearEnabled, false);
    refreshClearEnabled();

    //Optional text
    isOptional = attributes.getBoolean(R.styleable.CustomEditText_optional, false);
    refreshOptional();

    b.ivEndIcon.setVisibility(GONE);
    refreshEndIcon();

    //Counter
    isCounterEnabled = attributes.getBoolean(R.styleable.CustomEditText_counterEnabled, false);
    counterMaxLength = attributes.getInt(R.styleable.CustomEditText_counterMaxLength, 0);
    refreshCounter();

    //Elevation
    int elevation = attributes.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.CustomEditText_elevation, -1);
    if (elevation != -1) b.cardView.setCardElevation(elevation);

    //Border
    hasBorder = attributes.getBoolean(R.styleable.CustomEditText_hasBorder, false);
    refreshStroke();

    if (attrs != null) {
        //Pass through to edit text
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            int importantForAutofill = attrs.getAttributeIntValue(ANDROID_NS, "importantForAutofill", 0);
            b.etText.setImportantForAutofill(importantForAutofill);
            String autofillHints = attrs.getAttributeValue(ANDROID_NS, "autofillHints");
            b.etText.setAutofillHints(autofillHints);
        }

        //Focusable
        boolean isFocusable = attrs.getAttributeBooleanValue(ANDROID_NS, "focusable", true);
        b.etText.setFocusable(isFocusable);

        //CursorVisible
        boolean isCursorVisible = attrs.getAttributeBooleanValue(ANDROID_NS, "cursorVisible", true);
        b.etText.setCursorVisible(isCursorVisible);

        //InputType
        int inputType = attrs.getAttributeIntValue(ANDROID_NS, "inputType", InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        b.etText.setInputType(inputType);

        //ImeOption
        int imeOptions = attrs.getAttributeIntValue(ANDROID_NS, "imeOptions", EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_UNSPECIFIED);
        b.etText.setImeOptions(imeOptions);

        //MaxLines
        int maxLines = attrs.getAttributeIntValue(ANDROID_NS, "maxLines", 1);
        b.etText.setMaxLines(maxLines);

    }
    attributes.recycle();
    initListeners();
    initialized = true;
}

private void refreshClearEnabled() {
    refreshEndIcon();
}


private void refreshOptional() {
    if (isProgressBarVisible || !isOptional || isError || isCounterError || !isEmpty() && isClearEnabled)
        b.tvOptional.setVisibility(GONE);
    else b.tvOptional.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
}

private void refreshStartIcon() {
    if (startIcon != null) {
        b.ivStartIcon.setImageDrawable(startIcon);
        b.ivStartIcon.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        b.tvPrefixText.setVisibility(GONE);
        b.ivStartIcon.setImageTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(iconTint));
    } else {
        b.ivStartIcon.setVisibility(GONE);
    }
}

private void refreshPrefixText() {
    if (prefixText != null) {
        b.ivStartIcon.setVisibility(GONE);
        b.tvPrefixText.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        b.tvPrefixText.setText(prefixText);
    } else {
        b.tvPrefixText.setVisibility(GONE);
    }
}

private void refreshEndIcon() {
    if (!isProgressBarVisible && (isError || isCounterError)) {
        b.ivEndIcon.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        b.ivEndIcon.setImageDrawable(alertIcon);
        b.ivEndIcon.setImageTintList(ColorUtils.getAttrColorList(getContext(), R.attr.colorError));
        b.ivEndIcon.setAlpha(1f);
    } else if (!isProgressBarVisible && isClearEnabled && !isEmpty()) {
        b.ivEndIcon.setImageDrawable(clearIcon);
        b.ivEndIcon.setImageTintList(ColorUtils.getAttrColorList(getContext(), R.attr.colorOnBackground));
        b.ivEndIcon.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        b.ivEndIcon.setAlpha(0.42f);
    } else {
        b.ivEndIcon.setVisibility(GONE);
    }
}

private void refreshHelperText() {
    if (isError || isCounterError) {
        if (isCounterError) b.tvHelper.setText(counterErrorText);
        else b.tvHelper.setText(errorText);
        b.tvHelper.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        b.tvHelper.setAlpha(1f);
        b.tvHelper.setTextColor(ColorUtils.getAttrColor(getContext(), R.attr.colorError));
    } else if (helperText == null) {
        b.tvHelper.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        b.tvHelper.setAlpha(HELPER_ALPHA);
        b.tvHelper.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        b.tvHelper.setText(helperText);
        b.tvHelper.setTextColor(ColorUtils.getAttrColor(getContext(), R.attr.colorOnBackground));
    }
}

private void refreshCounter() {
    if (isCounterEnabled) {
        b.tvCount.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        refreshCounterText();
    } else {
        b.tvCount.setVisibility(GONE);
    }
}

private void refreshStroke() {
    if (isError || isCounterError) {
        setStroke(StrokeType.ERROR);
    } else if (hasFocus) {
        setStroke(StrokeType.FOCUS);
    } else if (hasBorder) {
        setStroke(StrokeType.DEFAULT);
    } else {
        setStroke(StrokeType.NONE);
    }
}

private void refreshProgressBar() {
    refreshOptional();
    refreshClearEnabled();
    if (isProgressBarVisible) b.pbLoading.show();
    else b.pbLoading.hide();
}

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
private void refreshCounterText() {
    if (!isCounterEnabled) return;
    int countChars = getText().length();
    String counterText = countChars + COUNTER_SEPARATOR + counterMaxLength;
    isCounterError = countChars > counterMaxLength;
    if(initialized && isCounterError) setError();
    b.tvCount.setText(counterText);
}

private void refreshHintText() {
    b.tvHint.setHint(hintText);
}


private void initListeners() {
    b.etText.addTextChangedListener((TextWatcherAdapter) (s, start, before, count) -> {
        //Do not trigger on init, only on user interaction
        if (!initialized) return;
        if (s.length() == 1) triggerAnimation(true);
        else if (s.length() == 0) triggerAnimation(false);

    });

    b.etText.setOnFocusChangeListener((v, hasFocus) -> {
        this.hasFocus = hasFocus;
        refreshError();
        refreshStroke();

    });
    b.etText.addTextChangedListener((TextWatcherAdapter) (s, start, before, count) -> {
        clearError();
        refreshCounterText();
        refreshEndIcon();
        refreshOptional();
        //Trigger all other TextWatchers, add them here instead of the text itself to trigger all internal ones first
        for (TextWatcher textWatcher : textWatcherList) textWatcher.onTextChanged(s,start,before,count);
    });

    b.etText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            //Trigger all other TextWatchers, add them here instead of the text itself to trigger all internal ones first
            for (TextWatcher textWatcher : textWatcherList) textWatcher.afterTextChanged(s);

        }
    });


    b.etText.setOnEditorActionListener((v, actionId, event) -> {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            b.etText.clearFocus();
        }
        return false;
    });
    b.ivEndIcon.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if (isClearEnabled) b.etText.setText(null);
    });
}

private void triggerAnimation(boolean fadeOut) {
    if (fadeOut) {
        b.tvHint.animate().translationY(-translationY * 0.32f).scaleX(0.7f).scaleY(0.7f);
        //This works but not with setText because getHeight return 0. The reason for that: i do not know
        //b.tvHint.animate().translationY(-b.tvHint.getHeight() * 0.32f).scaleX(0.7f).scaleY(0.7f);
    } else {
        b.tvHint.animate().translationY(0).translationX(0).scaleX(1f).scaleY(1f);
    }
}

public void setText(String text) {
    b.etText.setText(text);
    if (text != null && !text.isEmpty()) triggerAnimation(true);
}

private void refreshError() {
    refreshOptional();
    refreshEndIcon();
    refreshHelperText();
    refreshStroke();

}

@Override
public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    super.setEnabled(enabled);
    b.etText.setEnabled(enabled);

    if (enabled) {
        PictureUtils.saturatePicture(b.ivStartIcon, 1);
        PictureUtils.saturatePicture(b.ivEndIcon, 1);
        b.tvPrefixText.setTextColor(ColorUtils.getPrimary(getContext()));
        if (isError) setStroke(StrokeType.ERROR);
        else if (hasFocus) setStroke(StrokeType.FOCUS);
        else setStroke(StrokeType.DEFAULT);
        b.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(ColorUtils.getAttrColor(getContext(), R.attr.cardColorOnPrimary));
    } else {
        PictureUtils.saturatePicture(b.ivStartIcon, 0);
        PictureUtils.saturatePicture(b.ivEndIcon, 0);
        b.tvPrefixText.setTextColor(ColorUtils.getAttrColor(getContext(), R.attr.colorItemDisabled));
        setStroke(StrokeType.DISABLED);
        b.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(ColorUtils.getAttrColor(getContext(), R.attr.colorDisabled));
    }
}

public void setError() {
    isError = true;
    refreshError();
}

public void setError(String errorText) {
    if (errorText == null) {
        clearError();
    } else {
        isError = true;
        this.errorText = errorText;
        refreshError();
    }
}

public void clearError() {
    isError = false;
    //Its up to the user to decide that this will not be an error! So reset no matter if more is entered
    isCounterError = false;
    refreshError();
}

public boolean isValid() {
    if (isOptional) return !isError;
    else return !getText().isEmpty() && !isError;
}

private void setStroke(StrokeType strokeType) {
    switch (strokeType) {
        case ERROR:
            b.cardView.setStrokeColor(ColorUtils.getAttrColor(getContext(), R.attr.colorError));
            b.cardView.setStrokeWidth(4);
            break;
        case FOCUS:
            b.cardView.setStrokeColor(ColorUtils.getAttrColor(getContext(), R.attr.colorPrimary));
            b.cardView.setStrokeWidth(4);
            break;
        case DEFAULT:
            int color = ColorUtils.getAttrColor(getContext(), R.attr.colorOnBackground);
            ColorDrawable cd = new ColorDrawable(color);
            cd.setAlpha(54);
            b.cardView.setStrokeColor(cd.getColor());
            b.cardView.setStrokeWidth(2);
            break;
        case DISABLED:
            b.cardView.setStrokeColor(ColorUtils.getAttrColor(getContext(), R.attr.colorItemDisabled));
            b.cardView.setStrokeWidth(2);
            break;
        case NONE:
            b.cardView.setStrokeColor(null);
            b.cardView.setStrokeWidth(0);
            break;
    }
}

public String getText() {
    return b.etText.getEditableText().toString().trim();
}

public void addTextChangedListener(TextWatcher textWatcher) {
    //b.etText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    textWatcherList.add(textWatcher);
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return StringUtils.checkNull(getText());
}

@Override
public void setOnClickListener(@Nullable OnClickListener listener) {
    b.etText.setOnClickListener(listener);
}

public void setErrorText(String errorText) {
    this.errorText = errorText;
}

public void setHelperText(String helperText) {
    this.helperText = helperText;
    refreshHelperText();
}

public void setHintText(String hintText) {
    this.hintText = hintText;
    refreshHintText();
}

public void setStartIcon(Drawable startIcon) {
    this.startIcon = startIcon;
    refreshStartIcon();
}

public void setPrefixText(String prefix) {
    this.prefixText = prefix;
    refreshPrefixText();
}

public void setLoading(boolean active) {
    this.isProgressBarVisible = active;
    refreshProgressBar();
}

public void setCounterMaxLength(int counterMaxLength) {
    this.counterMaxLength = counterMaxLength;
    refreshCounter();
}

public void setCounterEnabled(boolean counterEnabled) {
    isCounterEnabled = counterEnabled;
    refreshCounter();
}

public void setOptional(boolean optional) {
    isOptional = optional;
    refreshOptional();
}

public void setClearEnabled(boolean clearEnabled) {
    isClearEnabled = clearEnabled;
    refreshClearEnabled();
}

public boolean isCounterError() {
    return isCounterError;
}

@Override
public void setFocusable(boolean focusable) {
    b.etText.setFocusable(focusable);
}

public void setCursorVisible(boolean cursorVisible) {
    b.etText.setCursorVisible(cursorVisible);
}

public boolean isError() {
    return isError || isCounterError;
}

private enum StrokeType {ERROR, FOCUS, DEFAULT, DISABLED, NONE}

// TODO: 13.10.2021 Text drawable needs to get bigger
public void scalePictureForText() {
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(30, 0);
    params.setMargins(19, 5, 0, 5);
    b.ivStartIcon.setLayoutParams(params);
}
}
```

And this is how I use it in another layout (I removed the constraints):

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:overScrollMode="never">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <com.company.app.views.CustomEditText
            android:id="@+id/et_number_primary"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
<!--Button that should not scroll-->
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can the code shared be more relevant? What are your custom views doing?

Comment: Well. I can share more code sure. But this is the minimal example of what I assume is causing issues. I post a picture of the custom view

Comment: Maybe you can perhaps have them as `<include>` layouts, that might help. Currently there is less information to go upon. Having two nested constraint layouts or even three should not be that big a thing, especially since something like `CardView` or `ScrollView` can only have one child layout.

Comment: Okay but this generally already solves the big question: Is this a bad design. So if it is not, I need to further investigate. Is there any possibility to see WHAT part of the inflation exactly takes this amount of time?

Comment: Have you measured the actual inflation time? Is it 500ms for just the line ` b = CustomEditTextBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), this, true)`? In the 500ms, are you inflating your custom view just once or multiple times?

Comment: You might consider [AsyncLayoutInflator](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/asynclayoutinflater/view/AsyncLayoutInflater) if you can't get the time down otherwise. There are restriction on its usage, but it may be worth a try.

Comment: @Cheticamp I am inflating my view multiple times. The fragment in question has at least 8 of those custom views. Loading only a single one is not that bad. I meassured inflation time on the CustomEditText which is 30ms - 50 ms each. Never heared of AsyncLayoutInflator. I will have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using ViewStubs for all of the optional parts of the layout, that is items with gone visibility by default. Then these parts won't be inflated until they become visible or are needed, which should save you some initial inflation time.

And maybe you could eliminate the MaterialCardView and then combine the constraint layouts once there's no MaterialCardView between them, less layouts means less inflation time. It looks like you're using MaterialCardView for curved corners and shadows, but you could try to make your own background with curved corners and shadows and then apply it directly to the constraint layout to get the same effect with less layouts.

Is there any reason why your custom view extends LinearLayoutCompat? Could make it a constraint layout and use merge as a root tag to eliminate one layout.

Also, you have a huge amount of code in your constructor which might be the biggest culprit, could you try putting timers in your constructor and logging how much time it takes for `b = CustomEditTextBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), this, true);`  vs how much time it takes for everything else in there to complete. That will tell you if the problem is really layout related or if you're doing too many things in the constructor.

Comment: Okay, step by step: Constructor takes most time for inflation: 44 ms vs 47 ms for complete constructor (It does not change a lot between different calls). So the problem is layout related. There is actually no reason for LinearLayoutCompat I just never created a custom view and copy pasted one from the net and changed it. I will try to change it to ConstraintLayout. About ViewStubs -> I will look into them. But are views that are invisible by xml inflated directly? About background: I don't know how to create one so that it will look exactly like before (dynamic sizes etc...) I will come back

Comment: Okay. So changing `LinearLayoutCompat` to `ConstraintLayout` did not do anything timewise. What was your intention with the merge tag? I tried to replace the first constraint layout in my custom xml with merge but get a compiler error: method inflate in class CustomEditTextBinding cannot be applied to given types;
        b = CustomEditTextBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), this, true);

Comment: I gave you the bounty. I could at least manage to get the merge working now. Altough it did not really save any inflation time. Trying View Stubs (For single views) next

Comment: Ah sounds like you may have already figured this out, but when you change the root tag to merge (which saves a layout) it changes the signature of the ViewBinding inflate method. So instead of `CustomEditTextBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), this, true)` try `CustomEditTextBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), this)`. I wouldn't promise a huge improvement from doing this but one less layout is one less layout so it should hopefully inflate a little faster with merge as root.

Comment: For making your own background to get rid of MaterialCardView, getting curved corners is simple enough. You could make a shape drawable with the color you want and whatever corner radius you want and it will be dynamic, so it will fit whatever size your view is. Shadows is trickier, you can try to mimmic shadows with a layer-list with a dark shape slightly shifted behind the primary shape. Or try looking into making a 9-patch with a shadow.

Comment: Maybe just ignore how it looks and try removing the MaterialCardView first and removing it plus combining the constraint layouts and see how much that speeds up inflation to see how much it's costing you. Btw, ideally you shouldn't be spending more than 16.7ms inflating (1/60) of a second as spending more time than that causes frames to drop. So it is concerning that you're taking 47ms total.

Comment: Looking at your layout some more, if this works how a normal EditText works in terms of the hint, you could try getting rid of your hint TextView and rely on the EditText you have with id et_text to provide the hint.

Comment: Yes. I found the mistake with inflate. I am using merge now. I also tried to just remove the card view and nested contraint layout which in my opinion cannot be the culprit, see: I have a layout that contains 4 of those custom edit texts. The layout inflation times without the nested layout where: 29ms,39ms,34ms,24ms. And with the nested layout: 33ms,32ms,37ms,30ms. This saves average less then 2ms (two nested layouts less). This cannot really be the issue. So custom background won't be the solution. Are barrieres a huge inflation problem?

Comment: I removed the barriers for testing. That actually made a huge difference. With barriers you can see the inflation times above. Without: 21ms,18ms,17ms,18ms. Combined with ViewStubs for single fields (Does that make sense?) I might reach below 16ms for one layout but not combined. But the question now is: What can I do to replace the barriers. I need the edit text to move depending on the start and end icons

Comment: That's really interesting that barriers are that costly for you. What version of constraint layout are you on? You could try updating it in the hope some performance fix has been made, in build.gradle `"androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2"`. It goes against conventional wisdom, but instead of barriers you could try programatically adjusting the constraints or positioning the views.

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, may have no effect on performance, but on many of your xml constraints such as `app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/barrier_end"` the @+id is unnecessary it could just be @id because you're just trying to reference an id not create a new one.

Comment: I am already on 2.1.2. And I probably will try either to remove the barriers and apply constraints programatically. Or I will (counter intuitive) move the left and right icons into another ConstraintLayout load this as ViewStub and constraint to that. BUT the +id made a HUGE difference. I can't believe it as Android Studio actually auto complete suggests the +id. I never thought this might make a difference so I just went with it. Inflation times with merge and id changed are now down to: 19ms,18ms,18ms,15ms. This is still not perfect but I have options here. Thank you!

Comment: Btw, I had a performance issue myself recently and replaced a single optional view, specifically a TextView, with a ViewStub. The TextView was fallback incase an image failed to load. And it was really helpful. Just a single textview being a ViewStub made my custom view load 1ms faster. When part of a list with a large number of items that's significant. So ViewStubs are worth it for single views when trying to be performant.

Comment: And I'm glad the @+id to @id worked for you! Really good thing to know and Android Studio is awful for not just allowing that but also generating it.

Comment: Well I am still not happy, as there are still lags but at least everything is down half to the time it was before. I assume I just have to many elements on the screen or really need to replace the card view with a vector drawable afterall. I just have no idea how these 9-patch stuff works. But it moved from priority high to medium as it is useable as it is now

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you some methods to analyze your layout :

- You can use [Lint](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/rendering/optimizing-view-hierarchies#lint) tool . Select Analyze (from the top bar) -> Inspect code -> select your layout file or the whole project if you want. this will automatically detect problems in your layout and will suggests fixes for it.

[image: Lint tool ss]

- You can also use [Profile GPU rendering](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/rendering/optimizing-view-hierarchies#profile) in the developers option in your device. This tool allows you to see how long the layout-and-measurestage is taking for each frame of rendering. This data can help you diagnose runtime performance issues, and help you determine what, if any layout-and-measure issues you need to address.

[image: Profile GPU rendering]

- Or enable [Debug GPU Overdraw](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/rendering/overdraw#dgot) option from the developer options to show which area of your ui is overdrawn.

[image]

For your help : [Inspect GPU rendering speed and overdraw](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/rendering/inspect-gpu-rendering#debug_overdraw)

Comment: Okay. Lint tool is not suggesting edits. BUT: All my Custom views are red and the bars are skyrocketing the complete screen. Very much above the red line. This basically proofes what I already knew. The layout renders to slow. The question now is: What will I do against it?

Comment: Can u share your custom view code ? The "some layout code" u mentioned...

Comment: Yes sure. I will update my question with the complete xml and java file. I highly assume that I messed this up completely. It is the first time I used a customized view. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

`ConstraintLayout` was added to flatten the view hierarchies and is not a light `View` to inflate. They are not design to be nested, so I would suggest you not to use them if you can avoid using them. In most cases `FrameLayout` or `LinearLayout` is sufficient.