# Huge performance issues with relatively small custom layout (spinner)

Tags: java, android, xml, performance, frontend

I already posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70423360/nested-constraint-layouts-and-huge-layout-inflation-times) on this topic and got ideas how to improve but sadly the performance still ist pretty bad.

**Problem**
I have the following layout which I use as a custom spinner. Also I timed its inflation as you can see below. The problem is that the inflation takes at least 100ms. Most of the times it is way higher (like 150ms) and above on my xiaomi mi 9 lite testing device. Imagine having three spinners displayed. Inflation time would be half a second (and actually is on some screens).

How to reduce inflation time significantly? If you have a look at the other post you will see that I am using a very similar layout for a custom `EditText` which 'only' takes around 25ms now after optimizing. I do not understand why the spinner needs so much more time.

Any help is highly appreciated. This would be an example of a logline `D/[Stopwatch]: CustomSpinner [Inflation]: 0 s, 195 ms`

```
public CustomSpinner(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.createStarted("CustomSpinner");
    b = CustomSpinnerBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), this);
    setClipToPadding(false);
    setClipChildren(false);
    int pxPadding = GuiUtils.dpToPx(getContext(), 8);
    setPadding(pxPadding, 0, pxPadding, 0);
    sw.logRound("Inflation");
}
```

And the layout (CardView for Shadow, TextView for the Spinner text - The one of the TextInputLayout would be above the front icon so I needed to add another TextView that takes over):

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:clipChildren="false"
   android:clipToPadding="false"
   android:paddingStart="8dp"
   android:paddingEnd="8dp"
   tools:parentTag="androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_label"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    app:fontFamily="@font/nunito2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/cardView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/cardView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:text="Label" />

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
    app:cardElevation="3dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_label"
    app:layout_goneMarginTop="9dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/til_spinner"
            style="@style/App.ExposedDropdownMenu"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"
            app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/actv_spinner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@null"
                android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
                android:inputType="none" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_start_icon"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="19dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_other"
            tools:tint="?attr/colorPrimary"
            tools:visibility="visible"/>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="45dp"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/iv_start_icon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_goneMarginStart="19dp"
            tools:text="Item" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_helper"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:alpha="0.44"
    android:textSize="9sp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/cardView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/cardView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cardView"
    tools:ignore="SmallSp"
    tools:text="Helper"
    tools:visibility="visible" />

</merge>
```

**Profiler Update**
I cannot fix my problem with the Profiler as it is Android Native code that is making the problems. The Inflation of the TextInputLayout that you can see on the picture takes 126.27 ms. But if I use the TextInputLayout without my CustomLayout it works just fine. So there is something terribly wrong here

[image]

[image]

**GIT MWE**
Do demonstrate the issue I copied all essential files into a new project. Have a look at this [git](https://github.com/dhoehl/custom_spinner_test).

Running this produces the following output on my Xiaomi Mi9 Lite:
CustomSpinner [Inflation]: 0 s, 295 ms
CustomSpinner [Inflation]: 0 s, 101 ms
CustomSpinner [Inflation]: 0 s, 96 ms
CustomSpinner [Inflation]: 0 s, 104 ms
CustomSpinner [Inflation]: 0 s, 134 ms

Comment: Are these metrics for a debug or release build? If the former I suggest you also get metrics for a release build which will be optimised.

Comment: I did not "hard check" the release built yet. But visually it takes too long. So just compiler optimisation won't be the solution sadly. But I will run a proper test tomorrow.

Comment: No change on release built

Comment: I'd try without using a custom font. Other than that I'd do some method traces and jank detection as part of the normal procedure to find out whats so epxensive about the inflation.

Comment: I used the profiler to find anything but actually this does not really help a lot. As the most time is consumed by the textInputLayout with is android native

Comment: Using your code supplied and a device with a Snapdragon 665 (vs the Snapdragon 710 of your test device) I get consistent times of around ~35m/s.  your test device should be even quicker as its a better CPU (on paper).  The layout itself has nested `ViewGroup`s, but I'm not seeing anywhere near 100m/s.  Having profiled it does take some time to inflate over flat layouts, but that is reasonable because of he nested view groups and complexity.  Have you tested this layout in isolation i.e not merged into another layout?

Comment: I will create a complete mwe on a new project and add the git here. This will take me some time though. Will come back here later

Comment: I updated the question with a complete git demonstrating the problem

Comment: I think you **don't** need `CardView` just to cast shadows. You can use `android:elevation` attributes directly.

Comment: In Galaxy M62, I got  max inflation time of 25ms with fastest being 17ms. Few suggestions that I would like to give: 1. Do not nest the view hierarchy a lot. For eg: We can achieve card like UI using `background` in `ConstraintLayout` so, you don't need `CardView` just to show shadow and rounded corners. 2. Always prefer `LinearLayout` and `FrameLayout` over all. 3. Put as less code as possible in the constructor.

Comment: I removed the cardview entirly. No change at all. The nested view layouts are not the issue. The inflation time out the exposeddropown somehow is.

Comment: can you post the entire `CustomSpinner` class? Maybe that helps us to solve your isuue

Comment: I posted the git with the entire class and everything you need to start it